# Python3 convert bytes to an array containing escape characters

Tags: python, arrays, image

This is preferably for Python3 but if this can only work on Python2 that is fine also.

I would like to to know if there is a method to extract escape characters from a string in python so I will show an example.

```
>>> bytes = open('pic.jpg','rb')
>>> bytes.read()
b'\\x00\xff\xed\x00XPhotoshop 3.0\x008BIM\x04\'
>>> bytesArray = bytes.split(escape_characters) # looking for a method to use here
>>> bytesArray
['\x00','\xff',etc]
```

Comment: @furas What? The OP is using `bytes` as the name of their file handle, shadowing the built-in `bytes` type.

Comment: What are you _really_ trying to do? Do you want a list containing all the bytes in the JPEG file that aren't printable ASCII characters?

Comment: @PM2Ring yes that's exactly it

Comment: This Python 3 code should get you started: `data = open('pic.jpg','rb').read(); a = [chr(u) for u in data if not 32 < u < 127]`. Change the 32 to 31 if you don't want space chars in `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is something like this.

```
bytesArray = b'\x00\xff\xed\x00XPhotoshop 3.0\x008BIM\x04'

def splitBytes(bytesArray):
   return [hex(i) for i in bytesArray]
```

Output

```
['0x0', '0xff', '0xed', '0x0', '0x58', '0x50', '0x68', '0x6f', '0x74', '0x6f', '0x73', '0x68', '0x6f', '0x70', '0x20', '0x33', '0x2e', '0x30', '0x0', '0x38', '0x42', '0x49', '0x4d', '0x4']
```